# Launching Bootstrap modal after DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have a very niche question here - not sure if anyone can help me. In order to maintain the flow of a site that I am working on, we dynamically re-order elements on the page after load because elements are enabled and disabled on the server and this varies on so many factors that doing it via JavaScript was easier.

Additionally, we jump between two and three columns depending on screen size so a server solution wouldn't cut it.

This runs in a script file inside the `$(document).ready();` function. On one page, we have a modal which is also moved by our re-flowing function. Because of this, jQuery doesn't recognise the element when we try and get it to call `$('#modalID').modal('show');`

Because this isn't hooking in to an event, I can't use jQuery's `.on` function so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to find `$('#modalID')` so that I can show it.

The biggest difficulty is that, because our re-flowing code runs on any page, we can't adjust that for this specific instance so I think I need a way to almost re-parse the DOM.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

***Edit***: code added below for clarity (hopefully)

Main JS file (The below functions run on `$(document).ready` and looks for all elements with the class "js-reflowitem", divides them into approximately equal sized lists based on the number of visible "js-reflowcontainer" elements and adds the items to their respective parent. This is to ensure proper vertical ordering (clients demand - I think it should flow horizontally which negates the need for all this!) or elements with no gaps regardless of which elements are rendered)

```
var colCount = 0;

function split(a, n) {
    var len = a.length, out = [], i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        var size = Math.ceil((len - i) / n--);
        out.push(a.slice(i, i + size));
        i += size;
    }
    return out;
}

function reflowPage() {
    var flowableItems = [], splitItems = [];
    $(".js-reflowparent").each(function (i) {
        flowableItems = $(this).find(".js-reflowcontainer .js-reflowitem");
        colCount = $(this).find(".js-reflowcontainer:visible").length;
        splitItems = split(flowableItems, colCount);
        $(this).find(".js-reflowcontainer").empty();
        $(this).find(".js-reflowcontainer:visible").each(function (j) {
            $(this).append(splitItems[j]);
        });
    });
}
```

One of the elements we *might* be displaying contains a button that posts back to the server to populate a modal (which is contained within the mentioned element so that the modal code isn't returned to the browser if there is no way of launching it) with some data that we need to act on (the modal in turn also needs to post back based on the actions of the user). This modal must load immediately so, on the postback caused by said button, we spit out the following JS (which is run *after* the above code):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').appendTo($('form:first'));
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    $('#btnCloseModal').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

The reason this is particularly complicated is that the page we are working on is actually an .ascx control which is rendered inside a "js-reflowcontainer" so we can't even render a button which we can click programatically.

I'm going to try and use the technique jalilIrfan suggested with some minor tweaks and will report back tomorrow. I will also see if I can move the logic to an ajax call to prevent some of the oddities caused by our repeated postbacks.

Please forgive the oddity of the code - a number of restrictions are in place that are well beyond my control.

Even if my plans for tomorrow end in success, I'd be curious if there was a way to find a control that has been added/moved since I can't believe I am the only person with this obscure requirement...

Thanks for the suggestions, guys!

Comment: Re-initialize the modal in a callback on the other function, or simply at the end of it.

Comment: What did you try so far? Plz show your code.

Comment: Added some code to (hopefully) better explain myself. There are a lot of separate components to this which makes posting coherent code a little difficult but please let me know if I can add anything else to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of $("#xxtt").modal("show").   Why dont you try having a hidden button click and trigger the button click when ever want like

```
    <!-- Buttons -->''
    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="hide showModal"></button>

     (**or**)

    <!-- Other elements -->
    <p data-toggle="modal" class="hide showModal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</p>
```

Then when ever you want just fire the click event

```
   $(".showModal").click();
```

Hope it helps